# Checar se Node criado com insertAdjacentHTML em um loop esta "visivel"

Tags: javascript, loop, dom, promises, fetchall

Estou buscando fragmentos de `HTML` com `fetch()` e adicionando ao `DOM` com a função `insertAdjacentHTML()` em um loop `for()`... a função que realiza esta tarefa esta em uma `Promise()` e do seu retorno (no caso de sucesso) uso outra função para modificar o conteúdo de partes do documento que contenham certo atributo.

O seguinte exemplo é fiel a questão:

```
let fragments = [
    {
       file: "navbar.html",
       mode: "prepend",
       target: "#body"
    },
    {
       file: "modal-cookies.html",
       mode: "insertAfter",
       target: ".drawer-menu"
    },
    {
       file: "footer.html",
       mode: "append",
       target: "#body"
    }
]

//
const __DEFINE__ = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        let urls = [],
            param = [],
            len = fragments.length

        for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
             urls.push(fragments[i].file);
             param.push({
                 mode: fragments[i].mode,
                 target: fragments[i].target
             })
        }

        let fetchResource = (url, i) => {
            return fetch(url).then(response => {
                if ( response.ok ) {
                    return response.text()
                }
                return Promise.reject()
            }).then(text => {
                return text
            }).catch(e => {
                return Promise.reject(e)
            })
        }

        Promise.all(urls.map(fetchResource)).then(response => {

            for (let i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                 let target = document.querySelector(param[i].target)
                 switch (param[i].mode) {
                     case 'insertBefore':
                        target.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', response[i])
                     break
                     case 'insertAfter':
                        target.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', response[i])
                     break
                     case 'append':
                        target.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', response[i])
                     break
                     case 'prepend':
                        target.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', response[i])
                     break
                 }
            }
            // após processar o loop "resolver"
            resolve()
        }).catch(e => {
            reject(e)
        })
    })
}

//
__DEFINE__().then(() => {
    // manipular o DOM após ter adicionado novos Node's
    let allTargets = document.querySelectorAll('.uma-classe')
    [...allTargets].forEach(item => {
        //
        item.innerHTML = 'Exemplo'
    })
}).catch(e => {
    console.error(e)
})
```

Aparentemente o loop foi processado e novos "Node's" foram adicionados ao `DOM` más ao executar a função que modificara partes destes novos elementos por vezes ao carregar a página "parece" que os "Node's" não terminaram de ser acomodados ao `DOM` e consequentemente as mudanças não são realizadas.

Dentro de `Promisse.all()` como poderia checar se estes "Node's" foram completamente adicionados ao `DOM`?

Answer (score 0):

Não muito tempo após perguntar eu cheguei a uma lógica satisfatória ... uma pena demorar a partilhar o resultado aqui, más nunca é tarde.

> Nas entranhas da questão

Inicialmente estava marcando classes ao longo do documento para mapeá-las com `querySelector` e "traduzir" seguindo um conjunto de palavras em um objeto `JSON` (um "dicionario").

Isso me fazia importar o `JSON` (fetch) no incio do script, atravessar o documento e adicionar as palavras correspondentes com base em seu respectivos índices obtidos de um atributo **"data-"**, algo como isto:

```
<a href="/contact" data-i18n-html="navbar.contact" class="i18n"></a>
```

Más, alguns "fragmentos" de documentos eram adicionados dinamicamente (fetch) o que me obrigava a atravessar o documento novamente para refazer tudo novamente ... era custoso, logicamente desnecessário e apresentando alguns erros que eu não estava sabendo lidar. A pergunta cita o mais grave destes erros.

> A alternativa

Precisei adicionar uma propriedade chamada **"translated="true"** para os elementos encontrados na "primeira rodada" realizada ao atravessar o documento e [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) para os itens iterados do resultado de `Promise.all` (text) e adicionados ao documento (nodes), isto me permitiu iterar apenas sobre estes **nodes** e todos os seus descendentes subjacentes com a classe **i18n** que (ainda) não continham a propriedade **translated** sem a necessidade de atravessar todo o documento novamente diversas vezes e garantiu que agora de fato todos estes elementos sejam "traduzidos".

> O resultado

A parte substancial que mudou foi exatamente esta:

```
// utilidades
const UTILS = {
    objectToString(o) {
        return Object.prototype.toString.call(o)
    },
    type(obj) {
        return (obj) ? UTILS.objectToString(obj).replace(/^\[object (.+)\]$/, '$1').toLowerCase() : 'undefined'
    }
}
// MutationObserver
let SpyDOM = (node, callback, options) => {
    let observer = new MutationObserver(callback)
    observer.observe(node, options)
}
// request resource
Promise.all(urls.map(fetchResource)).then(response => {
    response.forEach((item, i, array) => {
        // refuse "undefined"
        if ( item ) {
            let target = documento.querySelector(param[i].target)
            // initialize MutationObserver
            SpyDOM(target, mutations => {
                mutations.forEach(mutation => {
                    ;[...mutation.addedNodes].forEach(addedNode => {
                        if ( /element/g.test(UTILS.type(addedNode)) ) {
                            ;[...addedNode.querySelectorAll('[class^="i18n"]:not([translated])')].forEach(node => {
                                // "traduzir" este Node
                                funcao_traduzir(node)
                            })
                        }
                    })
                })
            }, {childList: true})
            switch (param[i].mode) {
                case 'insertBefore':
                    target.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', item)
                break
                case 'insertAfter':
                    target.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', item)
                break
                case 'append':
                    target.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', item)
                break
                case 'prepend':
                    target.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', item)
                break
            }
        }
        // if last item
        if ( i === array.length -1 ) {
            resolve()
        }
    })
}).catch(e => {
    reject('e')
})
```

---

Pensei em fechar esta pergunta mas, deixo esta resposta como referencia quem sabe ajude alguém.